# I can't return param value with xpath

Tags: xpath

I want to return the value of a param inside an object with xpath.

Example Code:

```
  <object id="player" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://merhad.333low.com/player.swf" bgcolor="#000000" name="player" tabindex="0">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="flashvars" value="http://merhad.333low.com/fqoyJxxS-2c2MSx-wGYmS3T1pkggIeiK7wpA7BbXXcK2sC4XYWehpBDV6CAK7CFH/s=awcmxqt5gYntLqHJ9ceP.flv">
  </object>
```

I tried this, but no result!
Example Code:

```
  echo $xpath2->query("//object[id='player']/param/@value")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should match the ID as an attribute:

```
echo $xpath2->query("//object[@id='player']/param/@value")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

btw, this will return only the first 'param' nodevalue

Comment: I acctually want to return the last param which has the name flashvars and I still dont understand why it's not working. Tried this: echo $xpath->query("//object[@id='player']/param[@name='flashvars']/@value")->item(0)->nodeValue

Comment: btw, it's ok I just want to return the first 'param' nodevalue

Comment: Hmm, you'll need the attribute value, so first fetch the node and then through PHP get the required attribute. Something like this:
echo $xpath2->query("//object[@id='player']/param[@name='flashvars']")->item(0)->getAttribute('value');

Comment: Tried this and not working: echo "".$xpath2->query("//object[@id='player']/param[@name='flashvars']")->getAttribute('value')->item(0)->nodeValue."<br>";

Comment: Also not working: $xpath2->query("//object[@id='player']/param[@name='flashvars']/@value")->item(0)->nodeValue

Comment: @HamadaBadran: Is the XML in the question the complete content of `$xpath2` - or it it just a fragment? Are you sure that `$xpath2` contains the correct stuff?

Comment: Yes it's correct...maybe you could help me if I tell you the link of the site I want to scrape.

Comment: The DOMDocument contains the correct xml?
echo '<xmp>'+$xpath2->document->saveXML()+'</xmp>';